# ftp error `530 Permission denied` on Redhat Linux System

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I am using right username still I'm getting the below error on my Redhat Server:

```
[root@server2 log]# ftp localhost
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
KERBEROS_V4 rejected as an authentication type
Name (localhost:root): root
530 Permission denied.
Login failed.
```

It is not giving the password prompt at all. My `vsftpd` service is running perfectly fine. I restarted it couple of times, but still the same.

I enabled `/var/log/xferlog` and `/var/log/vsftpd.log` to check for any potential error, but of no help.

Can somebody help me debug the issue.

Comment: Can you log in correctly with your normal user?

Comment: @terdon Yes, I'm actually trying it as `root` user, and normal `ssh` to the server is happening as usual. Normal `sftp` is also happening using same username and password

Answer (score 1):

You should *never* connect as root over FTP. It is an old and insecure protocol and there really is no reason why you would want to use it as root. Look into ssh or sftp as alternatives.

That said, if you really want to open this huge security hole, you will need to edit your `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file and add or uncomment this line:

```
 local_enable=YES
```

I really cannot stress enough that **you don't want to do this**. FTP does not encrypt passwords, allowing this will send your root password **unencrypted** over the network. That is A Bad Idea. Please use sftp instead.

Comment: This is already uncommented.


`anonymous_enable=YES`

`local_enable=YES`

`write_enable=YES`

Comment: @Siddharth please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Anyway, seriously, don't do this, it is extremely unsafe and there is no valid reason why you would need it. That repeated, see [here](http://www.gnutoolbox.com/root-user-login-vsftp/), do you have a user_list` option in your `vsftpd.conf`? Do you have a `vsftpd.users` file? This really sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101), why do you want to allow root to login via FTP?

Comment: I completely understand your point regarding the security part. But I just wanted to check which configurations are actually causing the ftp service to not work( on my test system). Coming back to the issue: i don't have any `vsftp.users` file, but I have a parameter `userlist_enable=YES` in the configuration file. But I don't think it should affect as I don't have the users file. Also I don't have any firewall blocking port 21.

Comment: @torden : Also I see a parameter `connect_from_port_20=YES` in the `vsftpd.conf` file, but my `/etc/services` says `ftp` port to be 21. Is that causing a problem ?

Comment: @Siddharth it is not a firewall issue, root login is disabled by all sane FTP servers because it is so pointless and dangerous, onbody ever connects as root over FTP. It is also not a port issue since you can connect as a normal user. If you have the `userlist_enable` option, you have a userlist somewhere. Read the article I linked to in my previous comment, it suggests possible locations for the file.